# Can SQL Polybase read data from Azure datalake gen2?

Tags: java, sql-server, azure, polybase

I want to setup Polybase to Read/Write data from Azure Data Lake Gen2.

So far there are no problems writing data into Azure via Polybase.

Code used:

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL AzureStorageKey
WITH IDENTITY = 'Some_Any_String', Secret = 'theazureKey00102037etcetc';
GO



CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE AzureStorage 
with (  
      TYPE = HADOOP,
      LOCATION ='wasbs://mycontainer@mylake.blob.core.windows.net',  
      CREDENTIAL = AzureStorageKey  
);  
GO


CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT DelimitedFormat WITH (  
      FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT,
      FORMAT_OPTIONS (FIELD_TERMINATOR =';',
            USE_TYPE_DEFAULT = TRUE)); 
GO


CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[TestTable] (  
      [ID]          INT         NOT NULL,
      [Name]        VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
      [SomeValue]   INT             NULL
)  
WITH (LOCATION='/2021/01/10',
      DATA_SOURCE = AzureStorage,  
      FILE_FORMAT = DelimitedFormatCom
); 



INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable] (ID, Name, SomeValue) 
SELECT 1 as ID, 'AAA' as Name, 100 as SomeValue
union
SELECT 2 as ID, 'BBB' as Name, 200 as SomeValue
union
SELECT 3 as ID, 'CCC' as Name, 300 as SomeValue
```

Result of  Insert

```
(3 rows affected)

Completion time: 2021-01-11T22:08:53.0447043+00:00
```

and I can see the data in Data Lake

[image]

If I want to read data from above

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].TestTable
```

The result is an error

```
Cannot execute the query "Remote Query" against OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "(null)". HdfsBridge::recordReaderFillBuffer - Unexpected error encountered filling record reader buffer: NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.clear()Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
```

I am using a local SQL Server 2019 - Developer Edition.

Java installed

[image]
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the access key using a SAS with both read and write permissions?

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=dedicated#credential--credential_name

Comment: I am simply using the instructions from Microsoft.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-configure-azure-blob-storage?view=sql-server-ver15

There is no mention of SAS, The connection is via wasbs. Inserting data works but there is the Java error on reading.

Comment: Step 2 in the doc you reference mentions creating the credential.  The doc I have referenced provides more info on how to create the credential correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating another external table once the data has been already stored, it may lead you to what is the problem, as I've also done this and didn't found any problem. Also, did you install the Java that comes with SQL Server or a different one? I found the error message here indicating a Java issue: https://github.com/lmdbjava/lmdbjava/issues/116

Answer (score 0):

I have installed SQL 2019 Dev on a vanilla Windows 10.
Then in the end all looked fine, no Java error for Insert/Select data into an External table based on Azure Storage Gen2.

I have used the SQL scripts posted in this topic.